# O Cryptic! My Cryptic!

Tags: poetry, cryptic-crosswords

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #48: Unusual tag mix](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7149/fortnightly-topic-challenge-48-unusual-tag-mix)</sup>

---

Please find below a poetic cryptic crossword. A very tiny cryptic crossword, because each cryptic clue is a poem. I must beg your indulgence in advance...since this is a tag mix, I felt the need to balance my respect for the form, rhyme and meter of the poetry against the Ximenean purity of the cryptic clues.
Anyway, I hope you enjoy!

[image: Grid]

**ACROSS**

**1**

Heliconia
Verges on pink, evenly.
You, becoming I?

**5**

Arthur's first sword, took from stone,
Left England at the last.
Retrogressing to the home,
where ships that founder rest.

**6**

It's a thing you will see in this rhyme
Thirteen-fold if your counting's sublime.
With a piece of your neck
Held to keep you in check,
Mark off all but the last one, this time.

**7**

Of all the kine and goats I got
from her Pop at our weddin',
tuberculous head, heart are found
in male kid, upsettin'

**DOWN**

**1**

```
             animals
     freshwater, inverterbrate
    flailing, unaging, radiating
microorganism, monster, making, myth
   alternating, tumbling, voiding
           dolor, almost
            everywhere
```

**2**

An em'rald, on a sapphire sea,
Long held in bond, but now is free
To nadir, abrogating plea
At last, unchained o'er blasted lea

**3**

YOU NEVER!
left us behind.
STOP!
the recrimination.
VIOLENT ENDS!
held in reserve.

**4**

Wound from which heart has passed;
sheltering, wherein caught
By wicked lady. Cast
into a bit of thought,
lyrical, measured 'gainst
prosody, past and hence

**HINT**

> 5A should be parsed as (4,3). 3D is an unusual modification of a common word, while 7A is fairly obscure. But also keep in mind that I really took the poetry tag to heart when writing this. In keeping with the poetry theme, there is certainly lyrical license taken, but I tried to keep it in definitions, both for the answers and for words that may be used in wordplay.

**OLD INCORRECT CLUE**

Former clue for 3D, left here to remind me of my blunder:

GO BACK!
on your promise?
YOU NEVER!
left us behind.
WE ARE!
without an end?

Comment: Are partial answers allowed? And, rot13(Ahzore 5 ybbxf yvxr Xvat Neguhe jura ur gbbx bhg gur fjbeq sebz gur fgbar, ohg pna'g erzrzore juvpu cbrz)

Comment: @102152111 I'd prefer no, especially since it's only been up for a bit more than an hour. If it goes a while longer, then I think it's perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm enjoying this one, but struggling on the last couple. If I can crack them I'll post an answer in rhyme - and that's a challenge to anyone else who gets there first! :)

Comment: @Stiv Threw a hint out, in case it helps with some of the last ones. I might have to give a bounty for an answer written in verse :-)

Comment: Ah, okay. I had 5A slightly off, which is probably why I was struggling with 3D and 4D (I have 7A already...). Let me see now...

Comment: Gah, my overlap between 3D and 7A now doesn't work, which makes me think my 7A is wrong after all. I had rot13(QBGNY) but I'm struggling to make the new central letter from 3D work... Hmm...

Comment: @Stiv...oh, sh!t! I clued the wrong word :-( The clue for 3D is incorrect. Please give me a bit to try to fix.

Comment: @Stiv Fixed. Should take you about 1 second now :-) So, SO, sorry about that.

Comment: Got it :) Now to try and write this up in between bedtimes!

Comment: bro the one time i wanted to give out a bounty on a question by others, you did it XD

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let's see if we can lift the lid,
Upon this puzzle's finished grid:

> [image]

And now unspoiler (if you choose),
For explanations of the clues:

> **ACROSS:**
>
>  1. '**HA**' from '**H**eliconi**a**' *verges*,
>  'p**I**n**K**' *evenly* - '**IK**' emerges.
>  A soundalike for '*you*' is '**U**,
>  This verse was written in **[HAIKU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haiku)**!
>
>  5. "**A**rthur's first" yields letter '**A**',
>  A *sword* in fencing's an **[EPEE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89p%C3%A9e)**.
>  '**S**tone' *left* is '**S**', *last* 'Englan**D**', '**D**,
>  All back (the 'S' inside): **DEEP SEA**!
>
>  6. '**A** piece of a *neck*' bestows '**A [NAPE](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nape)**',
>  *All but the last* of '(-thi)**S**' escape.
>  *Time* is '**T**', then - yes, you've guessed -
>  In this limerick, thirteen **[ANAPESTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anapaest)**!
>
>  7. '*Male kid, upset*' is **DAL** (good start),
>  '**T**uberculous' *head* is 'T', LOVE means '*heart*'.
>  In tennis, [that's an '**O**'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/word-origin-of-love-in-tennis) - in total,
>  Our dowry clue should give us **[DOTAL](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/word-origin-of-love-in-tennis)**!
>
>  **DOWN:**
>
>  1. *Alternate* and *tumble* 'm**Y**t**H**' - '**HY**' is what you see.
>  Then voiding '**D**(-olo)**R**' gives '**DR**; '[***A**lmost **E**verywhere*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere)': '**AE**'.
>  Then noting that the first half is some ?double [definitions](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hydrae),
>  Soon the answer **HYDRAE** should invade your field of vision!
>
>  2. An anagram of 'N(-a)DIR' less 'A' (the *last* of '*plea*'),
>  All '*o'er*' (around) an anagram of *blasted* little 'LEA'.
>  Look hard to spot what you can make - in just a little while,
>  You'll find the name of **IRELAND**, the famous *Emerald* Isle!
>
>  3. '*You*' is '**U**, '**N**ever' *left* '**N**',
>  'u**S**' *behind* is '**S**' and then...
>  (-sto)**P** (-th)**E** (-recriminatio)**N** and '(-violen)**T**' *ends* gives '**PENT**',
>  '*Held in reserve*'? Why, surely that could only be **UNSPENT**!
>
>  4. 'Wound' is **CUT**, remove its *heart*,
>  That's 'U' got rid of - done one part...
>  In a *wicked* **LADY**'s anagram,
>  And **[DACTYL](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dactyl)** says, "Well, here I am!"

Now all is said and all is done.
In solving this I had great fun :)
And so it's absolutely time,
To cease this speaking all in rhyme!

Comment: That is GENIUS! Awesome job, Stiv. Only suggestions for improvement are 2D rot13(erzbivat gur N sebz anqve) and 3D rot13(CRAG vf raqf bs fgbC guR erpevzvangvbA ivbyraG). Also, in 1D rot13(nyzbfg rireljurer fv nooerivngrq NR va nqinaprq pnyphyhf), but your method is more accessible, is slightly less Ximenean. Clearly you enjoyed, so I don't have to hope :-)

Comment: @JeremyDover Hey, it was good fun :) I'll adjust my poetry to match your intentions as soon as I get a moment later!

Comment: Oh, thanks for the bounty @JeremyDover :)

Comment: My pleasure Stiv! Thank you so much for getting into the spirit of the puzzle :-)